# How to link Anaconda3 environment to Blender 2.92 on Windows

Tags: python, windows

**My problem**

Since the release of Blender 2.92, my anaconda3 environment does not work anymore with Blender...
I have this error at startup :

```
Unable to find the python binary, the multiprocessing module may not be functional!
```

**My configuration**

- Windows 10 - version 20H2, build 19042.867
- Blender 2.92.0
- Anaconda3-2020.11
- An anaconda3 environment called "blender" with python 3.7.10
- A symlink to the conda environment as shown here :

[image]

- Several environment variables :

[image]

**What I already tried to do**

This configuration was perfectly working on my previous version of Blender (2.91.2).

I uninstalled/reinstalled everything, resetting the exact same environment variables, adding some others ... It still does not work ...

I saw a fix done in December 2020 related to this issue, but it seems that it only concerns developer versions of Blender : https://developer.blender.org/D9775

**EDIT #1**

I have found a little workaround to this problem. I have written a small
script that starts Blender through the "Anaconda3 prompt".
So I guess that the problem comes from a wrong configuration of the environment variables, but I can't tell what's wrong for the moment ...

Here is the small script :

```
@ECHO off
set system_drive_name=%CD:~0,3%
set anaconda_root=%system_drive_name%Users\%username%\anaconda3
call %anaconda_root%\Scripts\activate.bat
start "" "%system_drive_name%Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.92\blender.exe"
```